# Google+ OAuth2 on iPhone how to logout

Tags: iphone, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am writing an APP where students can login using goole+. I followed  GOOGLE Developer and successfully logged in and obtained the user profile information. Now I am trying to logout. I deleted the Application, signed out of all google accounts on safari , iPhone , cleared cookies, history logged in with a different google id but even after all the steps I am getting a refresh Token from google and it is returning me the same user profile with which I logged in of the first time. I know it has an expiration time but I wondering is there no ways to log out of it before the accessToekn expires on its own.

Comment: Delete the credentials and check in the code if any credentials are present.

Comment: From where should I delete the credentials ? i had manually entered the then in UItextViews. I have also deleted app to clear of any NSUserDefaults

Comment: if it's stored in NSUserDefaults, then it should be fine.

Comment: It is not stored in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: then search for it and delete it from where it is.

Comment: can you give me some guide lines as to where to search for it ? .. I have deleted NSUserDefaults , coockies history and iPhone mail accounts. Where else can i look ?

Comment: basically anywhere in the app sandbox (/var/mobile/Applications/SOME-UUID/).

Answer (score 2):

First, are you using the Google+ Platform iOS SDK?  https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/ This is your best resource for iOS development with the Google+ Platform API.

Then you'll have access to functions such as `signOut` https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_google_plus_sign_in, which clears out the OAuth 2.0 token from the keychain.

Comment: yes I am using Google+PLatform iOS SDK and there is a sign out button. But I am confused about the way it works in FacebookSDK that if i sign out of Facebook in mobile safari , i loose the session in the application aswell .. can this never happen with google+. Is there no way for iPhone user to clear up the OAuth2.0 from keychain in iPhone. thanks

Answer (score -1):

*(Sometimes I wonder if anyone reads these posts before they answer)*

To log out, in Google+ on IOS (Iphone, IPad, etc.), in G+ got to **settings** (Google+ settings, NOT device settings) and select **SIGN OUT**. That simple.